# MySQL consuming memory, seeking advice on how to configure it

Tags: mysql, memory, configuration

I have a small VPS that handles my 3 personal WordPress websites.

At a certain time MySQL started consuming more and more memory and actually (for months) the server has been running at 99% RAM usage with MySQL eating more than 2 GB alone.

My VPS is an `Ubuntu 14.04.05` with `MySQL 5.7.23` (I upgraded to avoid the memory eating bug), `2 amd64 CPU@3.9GHZ` and `3 GB of RAM`.

The webserver is configured by Virtualmin, with little to no modifications applied by myself (read after).

I tried MySQLTuner, and some other scripts but nothing helps.

I have only these 3 websites and every time the traffic spikes (these are personal websites, so "spikes" are maybe 3 users at the same time) the VPS crashes.

Can you please help me configure it to use lesser RAM or diagnose if there is an issue? 
I'm thinking about switching to MariaDB, but without changing the configuration I don't think that anything will change.

All the relevant informations are in this pastebin (posted Aug 7, 2018) for readability:

https://pastebin.com/UasHBcH1

According to [MySQL Calculator](http://www.mysqlcalculator.com/) it should only require 293 MB and I don't have so much visitors to justify this usage.

Comment: The server probably isn't sitting at 99% RAM used, it'll be using a large proportion of that memory for filesystem caching. Is there an actual problem you're trying to solve apart from the apparent memory usage?

Comment: If your server does indeed crash, you will need to determine the reason for that. Check the syslog and the MySQL error log for more information.

Comment: @mustaccio the webserver crashes because it cannot find free ram to manage the spikes in traffic, I already checked logs. I have an increased memory usage and my objective is to solve it.
If you check mysql calculator my configuration should use 293MB and uses more than 2GB, I can assure you that I don't have that much traffic

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ The memory usage isn't apparent, and maybe is caching. # free -h Mem: 3,0G 3,0G 0B 3,3G 0B 185M 
-/+ buffers/cache: 2,8G 185M 
But this memory isn't released by mysql and I can see the single mysqld process using that amount

Comment: @Aleritty Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf-ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report - after 24 hours UPTIME 
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop, top & mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I added the pastebin to my original answer, I executed everything except iostat because this server isn't really "busy"...
Everything is unedited this time

Comment: @Aleritty Thanks for the posts, iostat -x is needed to reveal your core count, please.

Comment: @Aleritty Do you have any SSD / NVME data storage?

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have 2 core as I specified before, and I don't have SSD/NVME this is just a small vps for personal use :-D

Comment: @aleritty  Sorry, I missed the earlier 2 core count.  The suggestions posted in the Answer on should be fine for your equipment.  Keep in touch, please.  View profile, Network Profile, includes contact info and Skype ID.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thank you, I'm updating my configuration with your advice, I let mysql run for 12 hours and thenlet you know if this worked. I have a doubt: you increased quite every parameter, but my scope was of saving ram... Will this give my server more beathing space?

Comment: @Aleritty  Could you repost as new dated entry, A) B) C) D) so we can see where your system is performing at this time and the Global Variables you are using in production?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
thread_cache_size=20  # from 8  mysqld takes 8 minimum, keep breathing room
read_buffer_size=1M  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_next count
table_open_cache=500  # from 80  to support 327 opened since startup
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G # from 128M for effective 750M for growth over time
innodb_log_file_size=64M  # from 8M to be larger than innodb_log_buffer_size
innodb_io_read_threads=16  # from 3 to speed up reads
innodb_io_write_threads=16  # from 3 to speed up writes
innodb_io_capacity=1000  # from 200 to increase iops limit
max_heap_table_size=16M  # from 12M to raise RAM capacity
tmp_table_size=16M  # from 12M should be same size and will reduce created_tmp_disk_tables
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct=90  # from 25 for reduced WARM up time
query_cache_limit=0  # from 525312 conserve RAM QC not being used
```

for additional suggestions, view profile, Network Profile for contact info, including Skype ID.

Comment: You made two typos in innodb_read_io_threads and innodb_write_io_threads

Comment: After some hours I can tell that this configuration use MORE ram, the process mysqld is using 3.3GB of ram (swapping of course)

Comment: My apologies on the typos.  What is response time compared to last week?  Do you have Skype available?

Comment: I don't need to tune performances, I only need to understand why I have so high memory usage

Comment: @aleritty  What is your response time compared to 2 weeks ago, please.  MySQL was designed to provide access to data as fast as possible many years ago.  If you want to reduce memory usage at the expense of data access speed, I can do that for you by reducing all the caching options in my.cnf, starting with innodb_buffer_pool_size going back to 128M rather than 1G, which is 1/3 of your TOTAL RAM of 3G.  Please answer my first question, how is response time compared to 2 weeks ago.  Thanks

Comment: @WilsonHauck, he is tight on RAM; most of your recommendations increase ram usage!

Answer (score 0):

With only 3G of RAM, plus running other processes, `innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G` may be too high.  Set it to 500M.  (128M is dangerously low for newer versions of MySQL.)

That change is the easiest 'quick fix' to get the system stable if it running out of RAM.

Also completely turn off the Query Cache via `query_cache_type = OFF` and `query_cache_size = 0` (not _limit).

If you can keep the server up for a day, please provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` and `SHOW VARIABLES`; there may be other things to tune to cut back on excess memory usage.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Meanwhile, I find that MySQLTuner and various 'calculators' all leave some details unaddressed.  My link is offering yet another 'tuner'; it may find something else.

Comment: I'm trying right now your suggestion, starting with the standard configuration, also I'll check your calculator, I'll give you the results tomorrow. Thank you